# Extra lines appear in a button when border radius is set

Tags: button, css

[image]

```
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color orange;
border-image: none;
border-style: none none solid;
border-width: medium medium 4px;
```

When I add a border radius of 4px,

```
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color orange;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
border-style: none none solid;
border-width: medium medium 4px;
```

[image]

the button gets a thin white line (left & right). Look at the image again to notice it. **How do I remove this line?**

Browser: Firefox 16.0.1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wgpUN/2/ here its look like good. can you make jsfiddle.

Comment: It's not showing lines to me - http://jsfiddle.net/TVzEJ/

Comment: @Dipaks can see the lines in both the code. Try with Firefox 16.0.1

Comment: I have the same version on WIN7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, on FF20, but it appeared to only be me having accidently zoomed in on the page. Resetting the zoom to 0 removed the line.